# jQuery AJAX not working when passing data to a PHP page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Validation part of my jQuery works, however, the AJAX part does not seem to be doing anything and I am wondering why?
It comes up with no errors and the registration works perfect without the AJAX, however, I have to use it.

HTML form in register.php:

```php
<form method="post" action="register.php" name="registration-form" id="register-form">
    <div class="form-group" id="email-group">
        <label for="email"> Email address </label>
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="password-group">
        <label for="password"> Password </label>
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" name="terms" class="form-check-input" required> I accept the <a class="privacy-link"
            href="privacy-policy.php"> Privacy Policy </a>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="register_user" class="btn btn-primary" value="register_user">Register</button>
</form>
```

jQuery with AJAX:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#register-form").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }).validate({
        rules: {
            email: {
                minlength: 6
            },
            password: {
                minlength: 8
            }
        },
        messages: {
            email: "Email should be at least 6 characters",
            password: "Password should be at least 8 characters"
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {

            var email = $("#email").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "register.php",
                contentType: "application/json",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    email: email,
                    password: password
                }
            }).done(function (response) {
                // some actions
            });
        }
    });
});
```

register.php PHP to handle it:

```php
if (isset($_POST['register_user'])) {
    /* Others */
}
```

I tried various "isset", but to no avail.

Comment: Show var_dump($_POST);

Answer (score 0):

there are few things wrong i see here.

1. maybe you should not catch the "submit" event of your form, i believe validation plugin take care of it.
   as per the doc : https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler
   maybe you should remove this part :

   .submit(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   })
2. in your ajax call, you submit 2 post variables `email` and `password`
   but in your PHP file you try to retrieve `$_POST['user_registration']` variable which DOES NOT EXIST because you didn't submit your form to the server's `register.php` file, you submitted only the 2 variables `email` and `password`

I suggest you using `FormData` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) so you only have to update the following piece of code to make it work (in theory)

example

```
data = new FormData(document.getElementById('#register-form'));
$.ajax({
              url: "register.php",
              type: "POST",
              data: data,
              processData: false,
              contentType: false,
          })
```

you can refer to this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/a/8244082/5856233

Comment: Thanks, so I have deleted .submit part and also changed the PHP file to have: if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && isset($_POST['email'])). Still doesn't work, but hopefully it's progress

Comment: why do you test the existence of the 'ajax' post variable ? i'm confused, i don't see where / when you create this variable so it should not exist

Comment: I think I have seen it recommended in some tutorial, but might be completely wrong. What would be the correct way to handle it in this case? I tried isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) too

Comment: please see my edit, also what output do you have from the browser developer tool console ?